# “I don't know whether/*if or not I passed”

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, idiomatic-language

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if#Usage_notes) reads

> *I don't know **whether or not** I passed* or I don't know **whether/if** I passed **or not** are correct but **I don't know **if or not** I passed* is incorrect.

Why is it so?

> **WhETHER OR NO**: 1. used as a conjunction as a variant of *whether* 2. under any circumstances: *he will be here tomorrow, **whether or no***.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/whether

IF https://oed.com/oed2/00111435 , WHETHER https://oed.com/oed2/00284376

Comment: "Whether" is invariably a subordinator, whereas "if" can also be a conditional preposition, which is indeed its more common use, so it is not surprising that there should be restrictions on the subordinator use of "if", motivated perhaps by the need to avoid potential ambiguity.

Comment: @BillJ preposition? **IF** https://oed.com/oed2/00111435 , **WHETHER** https://oed.com/oed2/00284376

Comment: Ignore most dictionaries. Modern grammar classifies conditional "if" as a preposition. One simple dictionary, though, gets it right [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/if)

Comment: @BillJ  Sum-of-Parts since [**NO** (adverb) 4. not: **whether or no**](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/no).  Furthermore, I don't know what meaning(s) of ''whether'' would [**whether or no**](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/whether) be a variant of.

Comment: "I don't know if or not I passed" isn't grammatically correct. "I don't know if I passed or not" is because the "not" in that sentence represents an ellipse of "I don't know if I passed or *if I did* not *pass*." "I don't know whether I passed," on the other hand, leaves the accompanying "or not" that "whether" requires implied, thus meaning "or not" but not expressly stating it.